Blender export causes Substance Painter "Missing seams on hard edges" error
It's rather a specific problem, I downloaded a model of a gun from the official CS2 workshop tools (provided by devs) for skin makers (Also, just to clarify, you got to understand that I can't change UV and anything related to mesh that changes it's geometry appearance, because it's a low poly model that is already in game and otherwise textures won't work for it). I imported this model to Blender, so I can separate different parts like slide, trigger, etc into different meshes so that in Substance Painter I will have geometry masks for my parts, I noticed when I imported my model in SP I had this problem :

At first, I thought this was related to my model (how I split it, did I apply UV seams, sharp edges, and so on) I then noticed that it was caused by this specific export setting in Blender OBJ format

And I know this, because when I import dev model in SP everything looks fine

But when I import this same unchanged dev model into Blender, and then export it without doing anything to it, it gets this problem (just like the first pic I provided before) So, basically I can't do any modifications, it breaks model for me, because of the export. Obviously I tried turning "export normals" off, and IT WORKED, it cleared all pink seams, BUT...shading is awful, that's how it should look :

That's how it looks without "normals":

I tried smoothing flat, then smoothing by angle, saving and not saving hard edges while smoothing, aplying hard edges myself, adding seams, nothing worked, also it seems that fbx export will always make these pink problems in substance to appear, since there's no option to turn off normals export, at least I tried and didn't find any. I've read related threads on this problem, but in my case it's already a provided model by devs, so I know for sure it's not the model that's causing these problems, I need to modify my gun, but Blender export will always cause problems :( Any help would be appreaciated. I will provide dev model (link to google drive), so that whoever tries to help can import it in Blender and export it back to SP to see if they have the same issue google drive link.

I solved it. I guess the problem was in the new obj export? I downloaded the stable 3.6 Blender version, then imported my model through the old obj import format, selected merged all vertices by distance, and ticked "sharp edges" on, and it calculated custom normals data embedded in mesh and created sharp edges there, for some reason when you do the same with new obj format it doesn't create any sharp edges when you tick "sharp edges"... so maybe it's a bug?
